# error detecting global http method from vue test

Tags: jestjs, vuejs3, vue-test-utils

I'm running vue3 and testing a vue component using the vue test utils library and in the component i am making an api call like this:

```
 const api = this.$http.publisher.fetchValidatedWebsites();
```

I have this global http variable registered

```
    app.config.globalProperties.$http =  HttpServiceFactory(HttpClient);
```

HttpServicefactory returns publisher like so:

```
const httpServiceFactory = (HttpClient) => ({
    publisher: PublisherService(HttpClient),
});
```

and in the PublisherService i have my fetchValidatedWebsites() method; but when i run the test

```
expect(wrapper.vm.$http.publisher.fetchValidatedWebsites)
            .toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
```

i get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'fetchValidatedWebsites' of undefined
```

Seems like for some reason the vm doesn't recognise this variable.

In my package.json:

```
    "vue": "^3.2.12",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^2.0.0-rc.21"
```

How do i go about fixing this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to register `$http` as a global mock in your vue-test-utils config.

Try something like:

```js
import { config } from '@vue/test-utils'

config.global.mocks = {
  $http: (HttpClient) => ({
    publisher: PublisherService(HttpClient),
  })
}
```